# Why do we consider Lebesgue spaces for $p$ greater than and equal to $1$ only?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Why do we consider Lebesgue spaces for $p$ greater than and equal to $1$ only and not for $p$ any real number?

Comment: James Roberts considered such [$L_p$-spaces, $0<p<1$](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.uconn.edu%2F~kconrad%2Fblurbs%2Fanalysis%2Flpspace.pdf&ei=wUDhUuScDNGrrgGs_YGYDA&usg=AFQjCNEqOW-Q56Xp_SKDFaAiVAhNG2yjhg&bvm=bv.59568121,d.aWM) as was able to construct in each, a compact convex set without extreme points; thus resolving a long standing problem in Functional Analysis. The techniques used in this construction, arguably, led to the resolvement of other problems concerning $L_1$.

Answer (score 12):

The reason is that we would like to define a norm by the following formula:
$$
\|f\|_p:=\left(\int_X |f|^p d\mu \right)^{1/p}.
$$
Therefore, we need to have triangle inequality (Minkowski's Inequality) which is available only for $p\geq 1$. See more details in Chapter $6$ of Folland's book: Real Analysis.

Answer (score 8):

Even worse. You can define a $L^p$-distance but the space is not locally convex. See "Examples of spaces lacking local convexity" in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_convex_topological_vector_space.

Answer (score 7):

As a concrete example, if we consider the domain $[0,2]$ and try to set $p=1/2$, then our "norm" would be
$$ \|f\|_{1/2} = \left( \int_0^2 \sqrt{|f(x)|} \, dx\right)^2 $$

Consider then

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & x<1 \\ 0 & x\ge 1 \end{cases} 
\qquad g(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & x<1 \\ 1 & x\ge 1 \end{cases}$$

We then have $\|f\|_{1/2} = \|g\|_{1/2} = 1$ but $\|f+g\|_{1/2} = 4$, violating the triangle inequality.

Answer (score 4):

Mainly because
$$
\Bigl(\int_D|f|^p\Bigr)^{1/p}
$$
is not a norm if $0<p<1$.

Comment: I have reverted to the original \Bigl and \Bigr instad of \left and \right. They loor better.

Answer (score 4):

As it is already mentioned, 
$$
\|f\|_p=\left(\int_X |f|^p\,dx\right)^{1/p},
$$
is a norm iff $p\ge 1$, since only for $p\ge 1$ satisfies the triangle inequality.

Nevertheless, the spaces $L^p(X)$, for $p\in (0,1)$ are quite interesting since they serve as the most typical example for non locally convex topological vector spaces.