# $L^p$-limit and pointwise limit

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

For $p\ge1$, I proved that if $f_n\stackrel{L^p}{\to} f$ and $f_n\to g$ a.e then $f=g$ a.e. But, how about the case $0<p<1$? Is it also true?

Comment: For $0<p<1$, "$L^p"$ isn't a normed space.

Comment: But is a metrizable topological vector space (not locally convex!). See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/648862/why-do-we-consider-lebesgue-spaces-for-p-greater-than-and-equal-to-1-only.

Answer (score 1):

For $p<1$, we say that $f_n\to f$ in $L^p$ if $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int |f_n-f|^p=0$.

Define $g_n:=|f_n-f|^p$: it converges to $0$ in $\mathbb L^1$ by assumption and $g_n\to |f-g|^p$ almost everywhere. We deduce from the case $p=1$ that $|f-g|^p=0$ a.e. hence $f=g$ a.e.