# Topological vector spaces vs. locally convex spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, examples-counterexamples

I'm taking a course on locally convex spaces and our lecturer mentioned that these form the most general collection of spaces on which one can still prove interesting theorems (like Hahn-Banach - which fails for the more general topological vector spaces) and which still have applications (exactly *because* interesting theorems hold for locally convex spaces).

But it still seems to me, that a rather large number of books do treat topological vector spaces (like Rudins book on functional analysis), which seems to imply that there is a need for this more general setting - otherwise why bother discussing the most general setting if there isn't any use for that ?

Can one provide me please with some example outside the theory of locally convex spaces which justify the need for a theory of topological convex spaces in a *plausible* way ? (By "plausible" I mean examples that arise in some natural way - in contrast to artificial examples constructed in such a way that fall out of the locally-convex-spaces-theory.)

(Notice that I didn't mentioned if these spaces had to be hausdorff - I would warmly welcome it, if both cases - hausdorff and not hausdorff - would be covered by examples.)

Comment: Rudins book actually discusses examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some time ago I attended a seminar in functional analysis, in which the speaker talked about the problem of finding Lipschitz maps between *quasi-Banach spaces*, of which the prototypical example is the space $\ell^p$ when $0<p<1$. Those are metric vector spaces that are not locally convex.

The fact that there are seminars on those things means that there are researchers working on them.

**EDIT** (Re to your answer). Actually, there are some spaces arising in harmonic analysis that are not locally convex. I only know the [weak $L^1$ spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Weak_Lp) $L^{1, \infty}$ of the Marcinkiewicz interpolation theorem, but surely there are others. I know very little of those things.

**EDIT 2**. I found the seminar I was talking about. [Here](http://www.icmat.es/seminarios/files/2013/ana-15-03-13.pdf) you have the abstract.

Comment: But working on such spaces doesn't automatically explains why they are indeed useful, applicable mathematical objects. I think I wasn't clear about what kind of example I was looking for: I'm interested in those kind of example that don't just arise out of a desire to generalize things, but that arise out of a need to solve some specific problem - like the usual $L^p$ spaces that can be viewed as arising in the context of solving PDEs. (Please see also the comment I wrote to the other answer).

Comment: Thanks for your additional explanations - could you please provide a different link ? the above one isn't working (I can't even connect to http://www.icmat.es/)

Comment: Neither can I. Must be a temporary problem with their server.

Answer (score 0):

The usual example of nonlocally convex topological vector space is $L^p$ with $0<p<1$. See [Why do we consider Lebesgue spaces for $p$ greater than and equal to $1$ only?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/648862/why-do-we-consider-lebesgue-spaces-for-p-greater-than-and-equal-to-1-only).

Comment: But are these spaces also *useful* ? To me this seems to be rather the type of artifical example that proves "that it can be done", but which doesn't arise in a natural setting. (Or differently said: Asking when $L^p$ for $0<p<1$ would make sense seems to me to be a rather academic question). I would of course accept this example, if such a space would pop up in some other context so that there would be some motivation for studying this space. (Please see also the comment I wrote to the other answer).

Comment: Regardless of the potential usefulness of the $L^{0<p<1}$ (and other) spaces, the idea of topological vector space is natural and serves to generalize the *basic* properties of the Euclidean spaces to function spaces. The local convexity appears after further study.